Prove line segments are equal in length
Given a circle and a horizontal line below it, draw a radius directly downward until it hits line $L$ at point $M$.
At this intersection point, choose $2$ points on the circle $A$ and $B$ such that the lines going through $MA$ and $MB$ intersect the circle at 2 new points, $C$ and $D$ respectively.
Drawing and extending lines $CB$ and $DA$ will intersect line $L$ at two points $E$ and $F$ respectively.
Prove that $EM = FM$.
Edit:
I immediately noticed $\angle{ACB} = \angle{ADB}$ because they both inscribed angles of the same arc. Likewise, $\angle{CAD} = \angle{CBD}$ because of similar triangles. I'm not sure how to relate any lengths, and I know the two triangles cannot be congruent.


What have you tried?  (Incidentally, this is not a site for "Here's my problem, solve it for me.")

@DavidG.Stork Edited to include my attempt, thanks for the feedback

If $M$ is inside the circle, this is sometimes called the "butterfly theorem" — the proof ought to be similar in your case :-)


Circle a and b pass through points FMD and EMC respectively. In circle a we have arc TD opposite to angle TMD and in circle b we have arc CV opposite to it.These arcs both cross  through  common point P of two circles . Where ever the center of original circle O is, the circle b passes through H which is the orthocenter of triangle IMP, since it also passes through two vertexes M and P of this triangle then it has equal radius to that of circumcircle of triangle IMP. In the original circle O you correctly found :
$\angle ACB=\angle ADB$
So $ Arc EM=Arc FM$
which results in  the equality of chords $EM$ and $FM$

Circle $a$ doesn't pass through $B$

How do you know that arc $TD$ is equal to arc $CV$? It seems that you are concluding this from the fact that both are opposite arcs of the angle $CMD$, but they are opposite arcs in different circles.

Can you explain why the circle must pass through the orthocenter? Everything else makes sense, thank you!

@Ilikecoding, I wanted to show it by animation but I could not find the option.
